# Printing from Numba CUDA kernel (In google Colab)

Tags: python, printing, cuda, google-colaboratory, numba

I'm trying to learn CUDA for python using Numba in a Google Colab jupyter notebook. To learn how to apply 3D thread allocation for nested loops I wrote the following kernel:

```
from numba import cuda as cd

# Kernel to loop over 3D grid
@cd.jit
def grid_coordinate_GPU():
  
  i = cd.blockDim.x * cd.blockIdx.x + cd.threadIdx.x
  j = cd.blockDim.y * cd.blockIdx.y + cd.threadIdx.y
  k = cd.blockDim.z * cd.blockIdx.z + cd.threadIdx.z


  print(f"[{i},{j},{k}]")

# Grid Dimensions
Nx = 2
Ny = 2
Nz = 2

threadsperblock = (1,1,1)
blockspergrid = (Nx,Ny,Nz)
grid_coordinate_GPU[blockspergrid, threadsperblock]()
```

The problem I however find is that printing the coordinates in format string does not work. The exact error I get is:

```
TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<class 'str'>) found for signature:
 
 >>> str(int64)
 
There are 10 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 8 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'str': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(int64)':
       No match.
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'integer_str': File: numba/cpython/unicode.py: Line 2394.
        With argument(s): '(int64)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         NumbaRuntimeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
       NRT required but not enabled
       During: lowering "s = call $76load_global.17(kind, char_width, length, $const84.21, func=$76load_global.17, args=[Var(kind, unicode.py:2408), Var(char_width, unicode.py:2409), Var(length, unicode.py:2407), Var($const84.21, unicode.py:2410)], kws=(), vararg=None, varkwarg=None, target=None)" at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/cpython/unicode.py (2410)
  raised from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/runtime/context.py:19

During: resolving callee type: Function(<class 'str'>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-12-4a28d7f41e76> (12)
```

To solve this I tried a couple of things.

Firstly I tried to initialise the CUDA simulator by setting the environment variable `NUMBA_ENABLE_CUDASIM = 1` following the [Numba Documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/simulator.html). This however dit not change much.

Secondly I thought that the problem laid within the inability of the Jupiter notebook to print the result in the notebook instead of the terminal. I tried to solve this by following this [GitHub post](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2035) which instructed me to use [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer#wurlitzer). This however did not do much.

Lastly I added `cd.synchronize()` after the call to the kernel to try and mimic the [c++ example](https://erangad.medium.com/1d-2d-and-3d-thread-allocation-for-loops-in-cuda-e0f908537a52) I tried to implement in the first place. This sadly did not work either.

It would be amazing if someone could help me out!

Comment: No string support on the GPU. What you are trying to do isn’t possible

Comment: But in [this c/c++ example](https://erangad.medium.com/1d-2d-and-3d-thread-allocation-for-loops-in-cuda-e0f908537a52) they seem to use it. But maybe they use some sort of CUDA simulator?

Comment: You are using numba. There is no python string support in the GPU in numbs. Please read some documentation

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution was to skip the formatted string and just use `print(i,j,k)` within the kernel instead.